# SQL ranking and ties

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking

I'd like to rank some data

If I used a rank function with ties, the same ranking is assigned and a gap appears in the sequence for each duplicate ranking.

example :

```
Value | Ranking 
1       1  
1       1 
1       1
1       1 
1       1  
2       6
```

**EDIT** : I'd like to know if it's possible have these two versions :

```
Value | Ranking 
1       5    
1       5 
1       5  
1       5  
1       5   
2       6  

Value | Ranking 
1       3  
1       3 
1       3  
1       3 
1       3 
2       6
```

I replace 1 by 3 because 3 is the median value of 1-2-3-4-5 (5 ties values)

Comment: do you need an update or  something like a formula for ranking column

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I'd just like to know the correct query to have this ranking rule.

Comment: What RDBMS and version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Value, 
count(*) over (partition by value)/2 + rank() over(order by value) as Ranking1, 
count(*) over (partition by value) + rank() over(order by value) -1 as Ranking2 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select 
    value, 
    RANK() over (order by value) 
             + COUNT(value) OVER (PARTITION BY value)  / 2,
    RANK() over (order by value) 
             + COUNT(value) OVER (PARTITION BY value) - 1
from yourtable t
```

If you're using SQL 2005, use

```
(select COUNT(*) from yourtable where value = t.value)
```

instead of the `count over` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (VALUE int);
INSERT @foo VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(6);

WITH RowRank AS
(
    SELECT
        VALUE,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY VALUE) AS rn,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY VALUE) AS rk
    FROM
        @foo
), AvgMax AS
(
    SELECT
        VALUE, rn, rk,
        AVG(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY VALUE) AS av,
        MAX(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY VALUE) AS mx
    FROM 
        RowRank
)
SELECT
    VALUE,
    CASE WHEN av < rk THEN rk ELSE av END,
    CASE WHEN mx < rk THEN rk ELSE mx END
FROM
    AvgMax;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want what I've been trying NOT to get.

```
ID # Rank
A   100 1
B   90  3
C   90  3
D   80  5
E   80  5
```

---

```
SELECT x.*, 
COUNT(*) AS myRank 
FROM myTablename x 
JOIN myTablename y 
ON x.number > y.number 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY myRank
```

Same results with ORDER BY x.number

Comment: Thank you Moath, that's how I wanted to post it.